# What is the difference between reverse and forward engineering in SQL

Tags: sql

I am currently learning to use SQL and I am confused about the fundamentals of the difference between these two. I am currently using the MYSQL Workbench.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: One is the reverse of the other, simple as that :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but I want to understand it in terms of SQL

Comment: @SharanDuggirala This question isn't really a good fit for SO, it's far too broad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Forward Engineering**
Going from a logical data model to a physical data model.  This is easy because the design includes all dependencies, indexes and relationships between the components of the data model.

**Reverse Engineering**
Attempting to reconstruct the logical data model from a physical data model. This is hard because not every database engine has the means to store the interdependencies between objects in a logical model, and sometimes these relationships are lost altogether. This information has to be somehow recovered by analyzing the data and inferring the missing relationships.

Compare this to compiling source code VS decompiling binary code.

Answer (score 1):

Forward engineering in SQL is using a script or database model to create or alter a new database:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering.html
Reverse engineering in SQL is creating a script or model based on an existing database:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineering.html